# OpenUI5 Treetable: get selected rows and their model data

Tags: javascript, sapui5

For some hours now I'm trying to get the model data of selected rows of a tree table.

I used this example: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.ui.table.sample.TreeTable.JSONTreeBinding/preview

Additionally, I added sortProperty and filterProperty to the columns. Until now everything works.

What I want to do is to submit the json data via ajax of all selected rows. for this, I need to get the json data of the selected rows.

What I tried:

```
var oTable = this.getView().byId("tableName").getSelectedIndicies()
```

and then

```
for(var i=0; i<=oTable.length; i++) { 
  this.getView().byId("tableName").getModel().getData().jobs[oTable[i]]
}
```

it seems that when I use the sorter and filter function, the indicies are not correct anymore. The indicies keys won't change.

any idea how to solve my request? thx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a small change you can do to get the right data in your for loop.

1. Get the bindingContext of the item which is selected as per the indices information.

> var sPath = `TreeTable.getRows()[0].getBindingContext()`

2. Get the data from the model as:

> `oTreeTable.getModel().getProperty(sPath)`

Comment: Hi, like I said: the getSelectedIndicies get not updated when I reorder with sortProperty filter. So it seems that there is a bug and/or I need another method instead of getSelectedIndicies to find out, which rows are selected

Comment: update: got it to work with getContextByIndex(). with this method, I got the correct and updated spath. Thx!

Comment: Please upvote and mark the answer as correct if it helped you :-)

Comment: your answer did not work for me (in oTreeTable.getRows()[i] I didnt had any value output with getBindingContext()). But your answer took me to the right way. thx for that!

Comment: just want to mention that I learned, when I'm using named models (like I nearly always do) I need to parse the name of the model into getBindingContext("model"). thats the reason why it was empty.

Answer (score 0):

this is how I solved it:

```
var oJSON = {};
var aData = [];
var oTable = this.getView().byId("TreeTable");
var aIndicies = oTable.getSelectedIndices();
var oSelect = this.getView().byId("selectStandort").getSelectedKey();
for (var i=0; i<aIndicies.length; i++) {
    var oTableContext   = oTable.getContextByIndex(aIndicies[i]);
    var rowData         = oTable.getModel("jobs").getProperty(oTableContext.getPath());
    aData.push(rowData);
}

oJSON.jobs = aData;
oJSON.standort = oSelect;
```